# How should i design the rest API if i have to create as well as modify the records in same DB table on form submit?

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I have react app where I could modify already added items and also can add new one. Then after submitting the form, i want to modify the existing one and create new records in database. Should i make PUT call for existing one and POST call for new ones on form submission?

Currently I am making a POST call to server and checking if the received object have primary key then update it in database otherwise create new record.

But I think I am not following the rest principles because I am updating and creating records in a same rest call.

```
@Post
createOrModifyObject(List<Object> obj) {
if(obj.getId() != null) {
    database.update();
}else{
    database.create()
}
}
```

I need to create and update records in a same call. How should i handle it? should i make separate call for create and update records?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT:

> The HTTP PUT request method creates a new resource or replaces a representation of the target resource with the request payload.

From the REST point of view it's fine use just 1 HTTP method in this case, as long as it's PUT

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Currently i am using POST, it seems I should use PUT instead.

Comment: keep in mind though that most developers will indeed go for POST to create a resource and then PUT to update it, despite the fact that it's not really an ultimate REST principal

Comment: Yes, that where i am puzzled what to use being within the boundary of good practice?

Comment: most of the time I see it being used when in micro-services when it is difficult for the calling micro-service to establish if a certain entity already exists. I wouldn't worry about it too much in your case though

Comment: PUT can be used to update or to create a resource but you shouldn't use the same method to do theese two things at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for you is to create another method that is updating the resources. Why? Because:

1. The best practice in REST design is to map the creation of a resource to a POST method and the updating of an existing resource to a PUT method.
2. Single Responsability Principle applies to methods as well, so you shouldn't have a single method with the responsabilities of creating and updating resources. You should split these responsabilities into two methods.
3. By splitting responsabilities into multiple methods you decouple the code. So if you will put a bug in the current method, you will impact the creation of an entity and the updating of an entity at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a POST request:

something:here/goes/user -> This one will create a new user.

And a PUT request:

something:here/goes/user/info-about-user
 -> This one will update a user.

I would handle in different request. This will make your code more simple and avoid nesteds if-else-then in one request.

Comment: Are you suggesting me to make both PUT to update and POST to create while submitting the form?

Comment: No, just to call a POST if you're creating a new record or call PUT if you're updating an existing one. You'll have two distincts URI and methods for it.

Comment: The URIs that you've provided are not valid from the point of view of REST

Comment: Of course you won't be using any actions on your URI. It was just an example.